# Python order of evaluation of nested power operands

Tags: python

In python 2.7 when you evaluate `2**2**2**2**0` you get 16 whereas the mathematical result is 2^2^2^2^0 = 2^(2*2*2*0) = 1.

Obviously the expression is being evaluated in the wrong order. I am scared of making a mistake. Is there a way to change this behaviour ?

Edit : The question is wrong, see below.

Comment: 16 is correct. The power operator is grouped right-to-left in both Python and in standard math notation.

Comment: Actually thinking more carefully about it you are right indeed :
2^2^2^2^0 = 2^(2*2^2^0) = 2^(2*2^(2*0) = 2^4 = 16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is clearly stated in operator precedence documentation, exponents are evaluated right-to-left.  The rationale is exactly what you demonstrated in your posting: there's a better way to write a left-to-right evaluation, so the programmer likely intended the *other* interpretation.